# Handling client threads

Tags: python, multithreading, networking, client-server

I have learned that in a client server network there are multiple client processes running in different systems and there is one server process running in the server machine. When the server receives any connection from client then it creates a new thread for it and handles the client.

I am working on a project in which a client creates multiple threads and the server also creates multiple threads for each client thread.

I cant publish the source code for my project here but I have written a small client server program in python in which the client creates a new thread everytime we press any key and the server should create a new thread for it.

I am getting some errors so I need help.

The code for server is

```
import socket
from threading import Thread

host="10.0.0.5"
port=7000
s=socket.socket()
s.bind((host, port))
s.listen(10)

def server(c, addr, i):
    print("connection successful with "+str(addr))
    while True:
            msg=c.recv(1024)
            if not msg:
                    break
            decoded_msg=msg.decode("utf-8")
            print("CLIENT "+str(i)+" : "+decoded_msg+"\n")

def main():
    i=0
    while i<=10:
            c, addr=s.accept()
            print("triying to recieve a connection")
            t=Thread(target=server, args=(c, addr, i))
            t.start()
            i+=1

main()
c.close()
```

the code for client is

```
import socket
from threading import Thread
import time

host="10.0.0.5"
port=7000
s=socket.socket()

def client(i):
    s.connect((host, port))
    while True:
            msg="from client "+str(i)
            encoded_msg=bytes(msg, "utf-8")
            s.send(encoded_msg)
            time.sleep(1)

def main():
    i=0
    while True:
            print("connection request sent")
            Thread(target=client, args=(i, )).start()
            i+=1
            if input()=='q':
                    break

main()
s.close()
```

Comment: what errors are you getting?

Comment: [Errno 106] Transport endpoint is already connected

Comment: The new client thread tries again to connect with the server so it gives this error...but I cant figure out how to tackle this problem